# Comparing two integers causes long query time

Tags: mysql, sql

My query:

```
SELECT  `suprayts`.`id`, `suprayts`.`username`, `suprayts`.`question`, `suprayts`.`suprayt_photo`,
        `suprayts`.`open_vote`, `suprayts`.`like_count`, `suprayts`.`dislike_count`
FROM (
`suprayts`
)

WHERE suprayts.id NOT IN (1)
AND  `suprayts`.`time` >1557944878
ORDER BY  `suprayts`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT 1 , 1
```

**This query takes: 0.0347 ms**

If i remove the following line:

```
AND  `suprayts`.`time` >1557944878
```

**It takes 0.0005 ms**

My time field is `int(11)` and indexed. What can be cause to this problem?

Comment: Why those ridiculous `()` where they are definitely not needed and add nothing

Comment: Fractions of a millisecond should not be a concern.  There are many things that can cause slight differences in query response time.  Also, .00000005 seconds -- 500 nanoseconds, if I'm correct -- seems absurdly fast for a query.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan. My guess is that without that condition on the `time` column, MySQL is making use of an index on the `id` column to return rows in order using the index, avoiding a "Using filesort" operation. With the condition on the `time` column, MySQL may be making use of an index with leading column of `time`, to find all rows that satisfy the condition, and then MySQL is performing a sort operation to get the lowest `id`. This is all just guesses. Use `EXPLAIN` to have MySQL show you the execution plan its using.

Comment: `My time field is int(11) and indexed` -- This sentence is quite confusing. Please include the indexes you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are pretty fast, and you don't say which indexes you already have.

Anyway, if you want to make it faster you can add the following index (if you don't have it already):

```
create index ix1 on suprayts (id, time);
```

Comment: I think the index needed is `create index ix1 on suprayts (time, id);`

Comment: @MarlinPierce I tend to think you are right. It's difficult to say without table stats, though.

Comment: Well, because it can filter by the bound on time first, and the sort comes later, so it needs to use time in the index first, and then later use the id.